# Spring Data Neo4j : relationship in specific order

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j, I have two entities, `Person` and `PhoneNumber`. `Person` has a 1-N relationship with `PhoneNumber`. I'm looking for a way to always have this relationship in a specific order.

Here's the definition of my entities (those are Groovy classes) :

```
@NodeEntity
class Person {
    @GraphId Long id
    String name
    @RelatedToVia
    Set<NumberRel> numbers
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "has_number")
class NumberRel {
    @GraphId Long id
    @StartNode Person person
    @EndNode PhoneNumber number
    int sequence
}

@NodeEntity
class PhoneNumber {
    @GraphId Long id
    String number
}

interface PhoneNumberRepository extends GraphRepository<PhoneNumber>, CypherDslRepository<PhoneNumber> {
    /* Empty */
}

interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person>, CypherDslRepository<Person> {
    Person findByName(String name)
}
```

Then I create and save some entities :

```
def num01 = new PhoneNumber(number: "0101")
phoneNumberRepository.save(num01)
def num02 = new PhoneNumber(number: "0202")
phoneNumberRepository.save(num02)

def alice = new Person(
    name: "Alice", 
    numbers: new LinkedHashSet<NumberRel>()
)
alice.numbers << new NumberRel(
    person: alice,
    sequence: 10,
    number: num01
)
alice.numbers << new NumberRel(
    person: alice,
    sequence: 20,
    number: num02
);
personRepository.save(alice)
```

And that's where I'm stuck : I would like to tell Spring - or Neo4j - to load the NumberRel relationship ordered by the value of the `sequence` attribute. I cannot find a way to do that.

Right now, the order is random. The following code prooves it :

```
(1..3).each {
    println "Looking for Alice, pass ${it}"
    def p = personRepository.findByName("Alice")
    p.numbers.each { number ->
        print "${number.sequence} "
    }
    println()
}
```

that produces this output :

```
Looking for Alice, pass 1
10 20 
Looking for Alice, pass 2
20 10 
Looking for Alice, pass 3
10 20
```

**So my question is : is there a way to have Person.numbers be ordered by NumberRel.sequence ?**

Answer (score 0):

if SDN can't sort the results, send the collection into a sort first -

```
(1..3).each {
    println "Looking for Alice, pass ${it}"
    def p = personRepository.findByName("Alice")
    p.numbers.sort{it.sequence}
    p.numbers.each { number ->
        print "${number.sequence} "
    }
    println()
}
```